# Shared clipboard and drag & drop bidirection function not working on Fedora 25 using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, bidirectional, fedora-25

I've been trying to set up Fedora 25 in Oracle VirtualBox for the purpose of learning Linux Command Line. I need the bidirectional functionality for both copy/paste and drag/drop tools but even after installing Guest Additions correctly they still don't work.

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

Settings->General->Advanced->

and change the setting under **Shared Clipboard** to "Bidirectional" and also **Drag'nDrop** setting to "Bidirectional."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order for Shared Clipboard and Drag and Drop functionality to work, you need to ensure that the Virtual Box Guest Additions including the 'virtualbox-guest-x11' package.

This means that your Gnome session has to run (and work) under X11, and not the default Wayland session.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that your OS is Fedora 25, while the virtualbox-guest-* package names might be Debian/Ubuntu specific. However, the resolution should be the same.